# Mathematica - multiple Sum, list as argument

Tags: sum, wolfram-mathematica

I am generating lists of arguments of this sort:

```
    list = {{i_1,min_1,max_1},{i_2,min_2,max_2}, ... ,{i_n,min_n,max_n}}
```

How can I use this kind of lists as an argument for the multiple Sum?

```
    Sum[f,{i_1,min_1,max_1},{i_2,min_2,max_2}, ... ,{i_n,min_n,max_n}]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Sum` has attribute `HoldAll` so you must force evaluation of `Sequence` with `Evaluate`.

```
list = {{i1, min1, max1}, {i2, min2, max2}, {in, minn, maxn}};

Sum[f, Evaluate[Sequence @@ list]]
```

[image]

You can't use underscore in Mathematica for variable names as it indicates a pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually used `Inactivate` on the `Sum` to keep it from calculating to get that image to show you how it works.